# Upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 resulted in boot process sticking with "The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready or present"

Tags: 12.04, boot, 12.10, upgrade, system-installation

I just performed an upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10, and everything seemed to go as expected. As the upgrade was finishing I was asked to restart the computer, which I did. Once I restarted, however, the boot process got stuck with the message:

"The disk drive for /tmp is not ready"

I left it for a while and nothing happened, so I restarted the system. This time (and every single time since) the boot process now gets stuck with the message:

"The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present.

Continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery"

I've tried several things so far:

1) Wait. I've waited 20+ minutes and nothing happens. After some time it also doesn't matter if I press S or M to choose one of the options, nothing happens (I have to press these quickly if I want to select an option).

2) Choose "skip" - all that happens is I see the Ubuntu logo screen as if it was booting, but nothing happens.

3) Choose "manual recovery" and it begins to load a maintenance shell  (I think that is what it is doing at least) but then very quickly the following error appears:

"udevd[109]: '/sbin/modprobe -bv pci:v00008086d00000116sv0000103Csd0000166Fbc03sc
00e00' [156] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)"

Once this message appears the system freezes on this screen.

I've searched around online but not found a solution so far.